# Pandoc: minimal headers for LaTeX output

Tags: hyperref, preamble, pandoc

I'm taking `mediawiki` text and trying to convert it to `latex` in Pandoc. All seems to be reasonably well.

However, I had to make sure to use:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
... pandoc output ...
\end{document}
```

to get LaTeX to work at all - specifically, importing `hyperref` wasn't particularly intuitive.

Is there a canonical list of packages I should be importing to handle any output from `pandoc -f latex` ? Or even just a list of "you should import this to cover this use-case".

(I ask because I have further problems deep inside my document, and suspect this is the cause instead of Pandoc producing malformed LaTeX.)

---

GarethJones is  absolutely right; using `-s` (`--standalone`) gets you the headers for free, and was exactly what I needed.

I also needed to use **xelatex** rather than latex in order to properly support unicode in order to parse some of the odder unicode characters (left-to-right direction marks, amongst others) and to ensure it output the correct ligatures (`fl` was being converted to Æ rather than ﬂ)

Comment: Were you using the -s (--standalone) option?  (Just a thought, having read the manual yesterday to determine if PanDoc could solve a problem I had.  It couldn’t, but for some reason that option stuck in my memory.  As far as I can tell, with the -s option, it should output the LaTeX preamble itself.)

Comment: This is totally the answer I needed, thank you. Would you like to make it a question so you can get a big tick? :)

Comment: You can also use a [template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates)

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to ask a [new one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Anyway, check slightly above http://pandoc.org/README.html#citation-rendering, `--latex-engine=xelatex`, but this only matters if you output to pdf directly, otherwise you just run whatever LaTeX-engine you want on the `.tex` file generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, since you seem to use `pandoc` to generate a `.tex`-file – which as [Gareth commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120961/pandoc-minimal-headers-for-latex-output#comment270109_120961), needs the additional option `-s` or `--standalone` if you want a fully compileable file instead of a snippet that you could `\include` yourself in another TeX-file –  it would be *your* choice afterwards to run `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`.

However, if you want to obtain a pdf directly (e.g. via `pandoc -t somefile.pdf ...`), then indeed you can choose `xelatex` (or `lualatex`) instead of the default `pdflatex` via `--latex-engine=pdflatex|lualatex|xelatex`. Note that in this case, the `-s` switch is implicitly active and doesn't need to be specified (though it doesn't harm).

(note that in pandoc 2.0 and higher, the command-line argument `--latex-engine` has changed to `--pdf-engine`.)

Answer (score 6):

A bit of searching for latex on the pandoc site shows

http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#creating-a-pdf

> Production of a PDF requires that a LaTeX engine be installed (see
>   --latex-engine, below), and assumes that the following LaTeX packages are available: `amssymb`, `amsmath`, `ifxetex`, `ifluatex`, `listings` (if the
>   --listings option is used), `fancyvrb`, `longtable`, `url`, `graphicx`, `hyperref`, `ulem`, `babel` (if the lang variable is set), `fontspec` (if
>   `xelatex` or `lualatex` is used as the LaTeX engine), `xltxtra` and `xunicode`
>   (if `xelatex` is used).